# jquery: display loader until image exists in a specific folder

Tags: jquery, loader, image-loading

I want to display an image loader & keep checking until the image exists in a specific folder.

The images requested are dynamically generated through a queue so I have no idea when the

image will be actually there, but I have its name in hand.

This process involve two steps

1st: POST request to submit image to queue script.
2nd: display loader until image is actually there, then displaying the image itself.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery image load , it waits until browser loads the image//

but it keeps waiting until the image is ready

```
http://api.jquery.com/load-event/
```

Comment: The image isn't actually there until the script creates it.
so it will get a 404 error when it tries and not finding it.